# How to add decimal point into number php

Tags: php, formatting

I am trying to turn `117` into `11.7` but am struggling to find any functions which I can use.

I've tried using  `<?PHP echo "£". number_format($item['now_cost'], 2); ?>` but this returns `£117.00`

Can anyone help please?

Comment: divide by 10? Then format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
<?php echo "£". number_format($item['now_cost'] / 10, 2); ?>
```